# Clean up data into a DataTable by Creating separate Groups using DataTable

Tags: c#, linq

```
FirstColumn  | DateColumn       | DataColumn       | GroupID   | InvalidDataFg
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header           |   1       |    False
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 123-10-234-3333  |   1       |    False
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header           |   2       |    False 
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 133-11-334-4444  |   2       |    False
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 345-12-332-2233  |   2       |    False
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header           |   3       |    False
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 123---2222       |   3       |    True
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | ---2334          |   3       |    True
```

I have a table with the field values like above.
To create groups I used foreach and created two separate DataTables

1. ValidData
2. InvalidData.

I am using C# to code this:

```
List<DataRow>  ValidData = below
```

```
FirstColumn  | DateColumn       | DataColumn
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 123-10-234-3333
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 133-11-334-4444
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 345-12-332-2233
```

```
List<DataRow> InvalidData  below
```

```
FirstColumn  | DateColumn       | DataColumn
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | Header
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | 123---2222
  CH         | 10/28/2019       | ---2334
```

Since Details3 is missing information. The Details are incomplete information, and is not completely empty.

Since my data does not have rowid's I have added them which might help with grouping.

Below is the code, please could you review and assist better ways to write this code.
I am not able to dataLines.Add(group.AsEnumerable().ToList());
Error:
Thank you.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    var dtable = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("GroupId"));
                                                               
    foreach (var group in dtable)
    {
    var InvalidData = group.Where(r => r.Field<string>("InvalidDataFg") == "True").FirstOrDefault();
       if (InvalidData != null)
          invalidDataLines.Add(group.AsEnumerable().ToList());
       else
          dataLines.Add(group.AsEnumerable().ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Could you add to the post expected `tableValidData` and `tableInvalidData` in a table format that you used to represent all rows?

Comment: What condition do you use to determine if details are empty? Do you consider a solution without using `LINQ`? In my opinion, for this problem a regular `for`/`foreach` fits better.

Comment: try using `AddRange` instead of `Add` as that is the one to use when adding lists of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not able to dataLines.Add(group.AsEnumerable().ToList());

The direct answer to your problem is this:

```
List<DataRow> datalines = ...
dataLines.AddRange(group);
```

You asked to review the code. If you plan to use this code in a bigger project for a longer time, then I see several problems.

You should work on your separation of concerns: als your classes are intertwined like spaghetti. This makes it difficult to use them without the other classes, thus difficult to reuse them in similar situations. It is difficult to test them, thus difficult to change them, as you can't test the effects of the changes.

Divide your problem into smaller problems: separate the concerns:

- It seems that you have three sequences: original data, valid data and invalid data
- Apparently you want to put these sequenced into DataTables, and maybe you want to extract them from the DataTables
- You want to extract all valid data from the original data, you want to extract the invalid data from the original data.

So good design would be to separate the DataTable parts from the extraction of the data in the sequences.

```
class OriginalData  // TODO: invent a proper name
{
    public string FirstColumn {get; set;} // TODO: invent a proper name, it is not a column!
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
    public int GroupId {get; set;}
    public bool IsValid {get; set;}
}

class ValidData // TODO: invent a proper name
{
    public string FirstColumn {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set;}
    public string Data {get; set;}
}

class InvalidData {...}
```

You need Tables to store the Data:

```
class OriginalDataTable : DataTable
{
    // Define the columns
    private DataColumn columnDate = new DataColumn(...);
    private DataColumn columnIsValid = new DataColumn(...);
    ...

    public OriginalDataTable() : base()
    {
        base.Columns.Add(columnDate);
        base.Columns.add(columnIsValid);
        ...
    }

    public OriginalDataTable(IEnumerable<OriginalData> initialData) : this()
    {
         this.AddRange(initialData);
    }

    public void Add(OriginalData data)
    {
        DataRow row = this.CreateFilledRow(data);
        base.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<OriginalData> data)
    {
         foreach (OriginalData item in data)
             this.Add(item);
    }

    private DataRow CreateFilledRow(OriginalData data)
    {
          DataRow row = base.NewRow();
          row[columnDate] = data.Date;
          row[columnIsValid] = data.IsValid;
          ...
          return row;
    }

    ... // Other methods
}
```

To access the data, there are two ways: do you think this DataTable represents a sequence of OriginalData, or can it give you a sequence of OriginalData? In other words: does it implement `IEnumerable<OriginalData>`, or does it have a method `IEnumerable<OriginalData> GetData()`? Whichever you use is a matter of taste:

```
IEnumerable<OriginalData> initialData = ...
OriginalDataTable table = new OriginalDataTable(initialData);
IEnumerable<OriginalData> dataToAdd = ...
table.AddRange(dataToAdd);

// If you implement IEnumreable<OriginalData> you can do:
foreach (OriginalData data in table) {...}

// othwerwise you do:
foreach (OriginalData data in table.GetData()) {...}
```

The code is similar:

```
public IEnumerable<OriginalData> GetOriginalData()
{
    foreach (DataRow row in base.Rows)
    {
         OriginalData data = CreateFromDataRow(row);
         yield return data;
    }
}

public IEnumerator<OriginalData> GetEnumerator()
{
    return this.GetOriginalData.GetEnumerator();
}

public OriginalData CreateFromDataRow(row)
{
    return new OriginalData
    {
        IsValid = (bool)row[this.columnIsValid];
        ...
    }
}
```

You also need procedures to Convert OriginalData into ValidData or InvalidData:

```
public static ValidData ToValidData(this OriginalData data)
{
    return new ValidData()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And of course a method to extract the ValidData from the original data:

```
public static IEnumerable<ValidData> ToValidData(this IEnumerable<OriginalData> originalData)
{
    return originaldata.GroupBy(originaItem => originalItem.GroupId)
                       .Select(... => ToValidData(...));
}
```

Do something similar for your other classes and tables. This seems a lot of work, but you can do it in 30 minutes.

Now the extraction from valid and invalid data is easy. To put the result in the other table is also easy.

```
IEnumerable<OriginalData> initialData = ...

// Put it in a table and add some data. Two statements only!
OriginalDataTable originalTable = new OriginalDataTable(initialData);
IEnumerable<OriginalData> dataToAdd = ...
originalTable.AddRange(dataToAdd);

// Easy to extract the data, and to convert into ValidData: One statement!
IEnumerable<ValidData> validData = originalTable.GetData().ToValidData();

// easy to put the result in a table
DataTable validDataTable = new ValidDataTable(validData);

// and easy to get the valid data items back:
foreach (ValidData validItem in ValidDataTable.GetData())
{
     ProcessValidData(validItem);
}
```

### Conclusion

If you will be using these tables for a longer period of time, if you expect changes, if you need to test the code, it is better to separate the tables from the data and to separate the data from the handling.

- Small procedures are easier to understand
- The procedures are easier to test separately
- It is easier to reuse them in other situations. You already saw this, when you created a ToInvalidData method: the code to extract the data from the original table could be reused
- It is easier to change the data: if you want to change for instance the display of the Boolean IsValid from 0/1 to test True/False, or TRUE/FALSE, all you have to do is change the table class. All other classes and conversion methods don't have to change.

And all this in about 30 minutes work!